# How do I fix a server side socket.io error?

Tags: javascript, server, socket.io, typeerror

I have the following lines of code in my index.js file:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const server = require('http').Server(app);
    const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

When I start my server with:
node --inspect server/index.js

I get:
TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function.

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need http server.
The correct way to start a socket server is,

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const io = socketio(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("connected");
    socket.on("welcome", (data) => {
        console.log("welcome message", data);
    })
});
server.listen(3000, () => console.log(`listen on port ${port}`))
```

The client,

```
const io =  require("socket.io-client");
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
socket.emit("welcome", "Hi");
```

Comment: I have a feeling that your answer is correct. The code that I supplied was from a tutorial on writing multi-user games with Phaser and socket.io.

I think that perhaps the tutorial was written before Phaser 3 and before socket.io version 3. It isn't the first multi-user game tutorial that had problems. For one of them I had to install socket.io 2.3.0 to get it to work.

Thanks for the answer. I'll see if I can squeeze it into the tutorial I'm using. Perhaps I'll also post another question specifically about Phaser 3 with socket.io 3. Thanks again!