# Passing errors from server to client socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, socket.io

I've created a node.js app that uses socket.io and want to pass errors from the server to the client. This is what I have so far:

```
io.use( (socket: CustomSocket, next: (err?: ExtendedError) => void) => {
    const error = new Error('Test error');
    next(error);
});
```

The way I understand it, I can throw an error by calling `` throw new Error(`Message here`); ``

However, if I use the code snippet above (`io.use()`), the socket.io connection cannot be created and the app doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: is this your complete server code ?? And what error are you getting while connecting to the server socket ?

Comment: @BhaskerYadav My server code also includes ```io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {})``` and the ```throw new Error('Blah')``` is in an ```socket.on()``` function (which is in ```io.on('connection')```. I don't get any errors, but the connection doesn't work.

Comment: Its difficult to figure out the exact problem without looking at the server and client implementation. You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65271823/2763906 I have posted a sample client server implementation